# How to dynamically change datatable using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm making a website which is responsive so I'm working with `datatables` since it is responsive I want to `change the datatable appearance` in different `@media screens`. What I want to do is when I'm in **desktop version** the table will be in a normal state and for **tablet form** I want it to be in [**FIXED COLUMNS**](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/) and when in **mobile version** I want it to be like 
[**Responsive Table**](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) like so. What is best approach for this? Do I need to create multiple table or just use a script? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. You need to destroy the first `DataTable` before initializing it again.

```
$(window).on('resize load', function () {
var width = $(window).width();
if (width < 720) {
    //for screens with less than 720px
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            destroy : true,
            "scrollY": "300px",
            "scrollX": "100%",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false
    });
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(table);
} else {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        destroy : true,
        responsive: true
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a single script to change the look of the table based on media screen properties. Below is an example script that would load different views of a table based on screen width.

```
$(window).on('resize load', function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 720) {
        //for screens with less than 720px
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "scrollY": "300px",
                "scrollX": "100%",
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "paging": false
        });
        new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(table);
    } else {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            responsive: true
        });
    }
}
```

Responsive and Fixed Column code is taken from datatables website links you have provided. This piece of code should fire on window resize and when loading as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882559/different-javascript-jquery-function-by-screen-orientation-on-mobile-and-browser#answer-13882873).

Comment: I think you are not reinitialising here. You are only doing either/or by using if else!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap's class as shown in given link 
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive